# How can save image using only path in Paperclip mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, paperclip

In my project I'm not using a form to send the image. I'm getting from path.

How can I do to save the image using only path?

I have this model

```
class Picture
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  has_mongoid_attached_file :avatar
end
```

I tryied this (In paperclip with mysql this works)

```
p = Picture.new
p.avatar = File.open('/path/to/my/image.jpg')
p.save
```

I receive an error if I make this.

Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError: Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I forgot the validation:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar,
   :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

This will fix the problem.